# Statistical test for power law samples

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, power-law

What is the t-test analog for testing against the null hypothesis that two samples come from the same distribution, if the two samples are distributed according to power law and have different number of elements.

Comment: You might find the framework described in papers [here](http://tuvalu.santafe.edu/~aaronc/powerlaws/) useful.  There's an accompanying python package described [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0215). Otherwise maybe just fall back to a suitable generative model and some likelihood ratio tests.

Comment: Do you mean a plain Pareto with common lower bound at 1? Or something else? Can you be more precise about the assumptions here?

Comment: Do you have any idea what distribution the data is drawn from?  Power law distributions lack a sufficient statistic and this creates other limitations you may not intend.  You could use Bayesian model selection with one of your hypothesis being that they are drawn from the same model.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a simple answer to your question without more details about the distribution. Power law distributions can have infinite variance, in which cases the large sample guarantees from the CLT will not apply.

If you know the variance of the distribution is finite (which can be guaranteed for certain parameter values) you can use something like the Wilcoxin ranked test detailed in

https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~wild/ChanceEnc/Ch10.wilcoxon.pdf

I would not rely on these tests completely without some simple checks based on the Berry-Essen theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem)

Essentially, you need some insights into the ratio of the third to the second moments of the distribution. This again, will depend on the nature of the exponential distribution under consideration

Answer (score 0):

If your distribution is a Pareto distribution, you can apply $\log$ to the values and you will get an exponential distribution. Then you can perform a t-test

Comment: The t-test only compares *arithmetic means*; the mean log is actually the *geometric mean* of the original data. Now if you have in mind a one-parameter "power law" ([which is not the only possibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Power-law_probability_distributions)) this would still be fine, but why would the t-test be applicable to exponentially-distributed variables, which tend to be extremely skew?